# JQuery Function Name Reference

Tags: jquery

I have a function set that I am trying to build which will allow defaults to be set using a $.fn function.  The catch is that I want to be able to know which function is requesting for defaults so that I can return the proper set "without having to send the function's name as a string".

I have see references to arguments.callee.name etc I am making the call from within another $.fn function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`arguments.callee.caller.name` contains the name of the calling function. Obviously won't work with anonymous functions/closures.

Comment: $.fn.setValFromCookie = function( cookieName, requestedSubValue ){
                var defaults = $(this).setDefaults( ??? );
    
using arguments.callee.caller.name it shows blank.
should I include a '$.fn.setValFromCookie = {};' to make the function global?

Comment: oops I noticed now that the use of $(this).setDefaults() is scoping it to the selector not to the function itself...